# Some key is nil after mapping

Tags: ios, restkit

I have a mapping as

```
@interface SynchObj : NSObject


    @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *server_id;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *app_id;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *operation;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *table;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *event_data_s;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *event_data_c;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fields;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *msgStr;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *code;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;

@end
```

And in my mapping class:

```
 mappingDict = @{

                                  @"server_id"    :@"server_id",
                                  @"app_id"       :@"app_id",
                                  @"operation"    :@"operation",
                                  @"table"        :@"table",
                                  @"event_data_s" :@"event_data_s",
                                  @"event_data_c" :@"event_data_c",
                                  @"fields"       :@"fields",
                                  @"status"       :@"status"
                                  };
 responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SynchObj class]];
    [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDict];
```

I receive the following response from Restkit

```
response.body={"response":{"operation":"create","status":"200","event_data_c":"2013-12-13 17:39:45","event_data_s":"2013-12-13 17:58:10","table":"MYTABLE","app_id":1,"server_id":31}
```

But server_id property is always an undefined or incorrect pointer.
All the others are ok.
Why?

Comment: (Almost) never `assign` objects! You want to make objects which have mutable subclasses almost always `copy`. For any other objects use `strong` (most of the time) or `weak` (for IBOutlets, delegates, etc.). Only `assign` primitive types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine it's because you should be using `NSNumber *` instead of `NSString *` for `server_id`. Use `NSNumber` for the `app_id` as well because the JSON is returning an integer not a string.

Edit --

Scrap that. It's because you're using `assign` instead of `copy` for the `NSString` whereby you are not telling the compiler that the values should be retained, causing the release of the object before you access it. You should still be using `NSNumbers` anyway.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *server_id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *app_id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *operation;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *table;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *event_data_s;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *event_data_c;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *fields;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *msgStr;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *code;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *status;
```